# Why is bash denying my shell script permission to open a text file with default text editor?

Tags: command-line, bash, permissions, scripts

I am in: 
 GNU bash, version 4.4.12(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

the script is: (note.sh)

```
 #! /bin/bash

edit="edit"

if [[ $edit = $1 ]]
then
    touch ~/.notes/"$2".txt
    $EDITOR ~/.notes/"$2".txt
else
    tree ~/.notes
fi
```

I was hoping
if I input in bash:
    `./note.sh`
I get output as if i had typed
    `tree ~/.notes`
But i want this script to basically accept arguments, so 
if I input
    `./note.sh edit new_note`
then if new_note.txt does not exist,
    `touch ~/.notes/new_note.txt`
then
(Gedit for me) text editor opening new_note.txt in terminal for  editing

the else statement works, but
`./note.sh edit new_note` returns

`./note.sh: line 10: /home/username/.notes/testnote.txt: Permission denied`

It does the touch but not the editor.
What is being denied permission here?

Thanks in advance! I am very new to both shell scripting and askubuntu and much appreciate any help

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In bash the variable `$EDITOR` is not set by default.  However, there is a command that will invoke the default editor.

For this command it is:

```
editor <filename>
```

To set the command to your choice:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config editor
```

Example:

```
terrance@terrance-ubuntu:~$ sudo update-alternatives --config editor
There are 3 choices for the alternative editor (providing /usr/bin/editor).

  Selection    Path               Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /bin/nano           40        auto mode
  1            /bin/ed            -100       manual mode
  2            /bin/nano           40        manual mode
* 3            /usr/bin/vim.tiny   10        manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

After choosing your default editor, then all you have to do to call it in your script is:

```
editor ~/.notes/"$2".txt
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: For maximum flexibility use `${EDITOR:-editor}`. This will use the value of `$EDITOR` if set and non-empty or `editor` otherwise.

Answer (score 6):

The `$EDITOR` variable is not set, so it is blank when reaching that line. Leaving `~/.notes/"$2".txt` for `bash` to call.
So `bash` then tries to execute `/home/username/.notes/testnote.txt` which gives *permission denied* because there is no executable flag set for the file.

As Terrance already mentioned, call the command `editor` directly or assign a valid texteditor to the variable `$EDITOR`.

```
EDITOR="/usr/bin/vi"
```

or

```
EDITOR="/usr/bin/vim"
```

or

```
EDITOR="/bin/nano"
```

or any other editor of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

**In brief**: On Debian/Ubuntu: run `sensible-editor`.

---

But about the error you see:

As others have mentioned, if `EDITOR` is empty or not set, the unquoted expansion of `$EDITOR` results in nothing, so what the shell sees as the first word on the line, and as the command is the filename that comes after.

A *quoted* expansion `"$EDITOR"` would result in an empty word, which would give you a confusing error when the shell tries to run an empty string as a command:

```
bash: : command not found
```

You probably want to set a fallback in the case `EDITOR` is not set. You can use the `${par:-word}` expansion for that. E.g. `"${EDITOR:-vi}"` would use the value of `EDITOR`, and if it's empty or unset, fall back to `vi`.

Then there's also `VISUAL`, which pretty much serves the same function, so you could check both: `"${VISUAL:-${EDITOR:-vi}}"`.

---

**On Ubuntu and other Debian-based systems you should use `sensible-editor`** (instead of `editor`, `vi` or `nano`) **since it allows a *per-user* setting of the default editor**, unlike `editor` which depends on the system-wide symlink set by `update-alternatives`.

`sensible-editor` also checks `VISUAL` and `EDITOR`, so you don't need to check them explicitly, but could just run `sensible-editor $file` and it will do the right thing.

(Even if yours may be a single-user system, it's good to keep in mind that multi-user systems do exist, and you can have multiple users even on a desktop machine.)